# How to call two methods from one button on a WPF form (C#)

Tags: c#, methods

How do I code this in a way that allows me to run two methods when one button is clicked on a form.

Run CalculateArea() and CalculatePerimeter() when I click btnCalculate.

I'm not really sure what I'm missing here, am I putting something in the wrong place or am I missing something.

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace PracticalExam1
    {
        public partial class frmMain : Form
        {

            public frmMain()
             {
                InitializeComponent();

            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();

        }

        public class Rectangle
        {
            public float Length;
            public float Width;
            public float Area;
            public float Perimeter;

        }

        public void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void CalculateArea(float length, float width, float area)
        {
            area = length * width;
            txtArea.Text = Convert.ToString(area);
        }       

        public void CalculatePerimeter(float length, float width, float perimeter)
        {
            perimeter = length * 2 + width * 2;
            txtPerimeter.Text = Convert.ToString(perimeter);
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CalculateArea();
            CalculatePerimeter();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to pass some arguments to methods which have parameters? oh, and System.Windows.Forms.Form is definitely NOT a WPF form

Comment: This code does not compile, because you did not pass parameters to the methods.

Apart from the above, it is always good to state the problem you experience. In this case the code does not compile and compiler gives you errors. It is good to attach all this information if you decide to post...

Comment: You didn't pass arguments to methods...

Comment: I am trying to calculate them from txtLength and txtWidth on the frmMain, not exactly sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how i wrote the **CalculateArea** method...

```
private double CalculateArea(double h, double b)
{
  return h * b;
}

double area = CalculateArea(12.5, 20);
```

You don't need to pass the `area` argument... just return the result and assign it to a variable.
If you understood what I am saying, you should be able to do the `CalculatePerimeter` method too.

**Take a break coding and revise C# methods and variables**

Comment: How to I pull the values from txtLength and txtWidth on the form?

Comment: You have two ways:
1-Permit only double or integer values on the textBoxes;
2-Try to parse the value into a double.

You can achieve textBoxes values like this: `textBoxName.Text`